# Count most frequent 100 words from sentences in Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have text reviews in one column in Pandas dataframe and I want to count the N-most frequent words with their frequency counts (in whole column - NOT in single cell). One approach is Counting the words using a counter, by iterating through each row. Is there a better alternative?

Representative data.

```
0    a heartening tale of small victories and endu
1    no sophomore slump for director sam mendes  w
2    if you are an actor who can relate to the sea
3    it's this memory-as-identity obviation that g
4    boyd's screenplay ( co-written with guardian
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(" ".join(df["text"]).split()).most_common(100)
```

I'm pretty sure this would give you what you want. (You might have to remove some non-words from the counter result before calling `most_common`.)

Comment: Minor addition, I may consider lowercasing the column first and then take the result like `Counter(" ".join(df["text"].str.lower()).split()).most_common(100)` ? `My` and `my` should be treated as one word?

Comment: Interestingly, you may notice from the benchmarks `value_counts` is faster than `Counter` for large number of rows.

Comment: good job :) +1 I am not familiar enough with pandas to know the pandas way for this :P (but you get an upvote for me from it :)

Answer (score 30):

Along with @Joran's solution you could also you use `series.value_counts` for large amounts of text/rows

```
 pd.Series(' '.join(df['text']).lower().split()).value_counts()[:100]
```

You would find from the benchmarks `series.value_counts` seems twice (2X) faster than `Counter` method

*For Movie Reviews dataset of 3000 rows, totaling 400K characters and 70k words.*

```
In [448]: %timeit Counter(" ".join(df.text).lower().split()).most_common(100)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.2 ms per loop

In [449]: %timeit pd.Series(' '.join(df.text).lower().split()).value_counts()[:100]
10 loops, best of 3: 27.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is kinda astonishing, one (I) would think that iterating and updating a Counter would be faster than doing the string manipulation, let alone building up a Series. But it turns out that the updating rather than splitting is the slow part... (and pandas uses cython/klib rather than a plain dict).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to disagree with @Zero

For 91,000 strings (email address), I found `collections.Counter(..).most_common(n)` to be faster. *however,* `series.value_counts` *may still be faster at if they are over 500k words*

```py
%%timeit
[i[0] for i in Counter(data_requester['requester'].values).most_common(5)]
# 13 ms ± 321 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
data_requester['requester'].value_counts().index[:5]
# 22.2 ms ± 597 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```