# Count individual words in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm trying to count the individual words in a column of my data frame. It looks like this. In reality the texts are Tweets.

```
text
this is some text that I want to count
That's all I wan't
It is unicode text
```

So what I found from other stackoverflow questions is that I could use the following:

[Count most frequent 100 words from sentences in Dataframe Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903025/count-most-frequent-100-words-from-sentences-in-dataframe-pandas)

[Count distinct words from a Pandas Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936957/count-distinct-words-from-a-pandas-data-frame)

My df is called result and this is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
result2 = Counter(" ".join(result['text'].values.tolist()).split(" ")).items()
result2
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2f018a9f912d> in <module>()
      1 from collections import Counter
----> 2 result2 = Counter(" ".join(result['text'].values.tolist()).split(" ")).items()
      3 result2
TypeError: sequence item 25831: expected str instance, float found
```

The dtype of text is object, which from what I understand is correct for unicode text data.

Comment: Apparantely there are float values in your dataframe, what do you want to do with them? You want to count them as well?

Comment: Since these texts are supposed to be all Tweets I want to count them as well. If this column also contains float values does that mean that I collected tweets that are just numbers? (makes me curious which ones are float)

Comment: yea that is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is occurring because some of the values in your series (`result['text']`) is of type `float`. If you want to consider them during `' '.join()` as well, then you would need to convert the floats to string before passing them onto `str.join()`.

You can use `Series.astype()` to convert all the values to string. Also, you really do not need to use `.tolist()` , you can simply give the series to `str.join()` as well. Example -

```
result2 = Counter(" ".join(result['text'].astype(str)).split(" ")).items()
```

Demo -

```
In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame([['blah'],['asd'],[10.1]],columns=['A'])

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
      A
0  blah
1   asd
2  10.1

In [62]: ' '.join(df['A'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-77e78c2ee142> in <module>()
----> 1 ' '.join(df['A'])

TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found

In [63]: ' '.join(df['A'].astype(str))
Out[63]: 'blah asd 10.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Now the output is in a dict, Would it be logical to move it back to a pandas data frame or somehow just keep working within a df?

Comment: depends on what work you intend to do. but my guess is dataframe would be faster if you are intending to do some kind of analysis.

Comment: Generic answer to generic question :D When I have a specific question I will make a new question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In the end I went with the following code:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
words = pd.Series(' '.join(result['text'].astype(str)).lower().split(" ")).value_counts()[:100]
words
```

The problem was however solved by Anand S Kumar.