# TO get count of list of words from a pandas data frame where each column is a list of words

Tags: python, pandas

So i basically have a pandas data frame :
Say

`1. oshin oshin1 oshin2`

`2. oshin3  oshin2  oshin4`

I want to get a counter in such a way (basically my output) should be:

`oshin:1
oshin1:1
oshin2:2
oshin3:1
oshin4:1`

Such that i can export the output to a csv  file as it is going to be really long.
How do i do it in pandas?
OR 
how can i do it for any column in pandas for a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first create `lists` in each column by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then convert to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and flat by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). Convert to `list` and apply `Counter`, last convert to `dict`:

```
print (df)
                    col
0   oshin oshin1 oshin2
1  oshin3 oshin2 oshin4

from collections import Counter

cols = ['col', ...]
d = dict(Counter(np.concatenate(df[cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.split()) \
                                        .values.ravel().tolist())))
print (d)
{'oshin3': 1, 'oshin4': 1, 'oshin1': 1, 'oshin': 1, 'oshin2': 2}
```

But if only one column (thanks [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735777/to-get-count-of-list-of-words-from-a-pandas-data-frame-where-each-column-is-a-li/44735807?noredirect=1#comment76453443_44735807)):

```
d = dict(df['col'].str.split().map(Counter).sum())
print (d)
{'oshin3': 1, 'oshin4': 1, 'oshin1': 1, 'oshin': 1, 'oshin2': 2}
```

EDIT:

Another faster solution from [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735777/to-get-count-of-list-of-words-from-a-pandas-data-frame-where-each-column-is-a-li/44735807?noredirect=1#comment76458967_44735807), thank you:

```
d = pd.Series(' '.join(df['col']).split()).value_counts().to_dict()
print (d)
{'oshin3': 1, 'oshin4': 1, 'oshin1': 1, 'oshin': 1, 'oshin2': 2}
```

Comment: Given a single column `col` - you could use: `df.col.str.split().map(Counter).sum()`

Comment: Another way `pd.Series(' '.join(df['col']).split()).value_counts().to_dict()` Sometimes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29904212/2137255 `value_counts` can be faster than `Counter`